# removing reference to googlesitemaps in silverstripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

I've recently moved a silverstripe site to a new server. Since then it's bringing up the error:

Fatal error: Class 'SiteTreeDecorator' not found in /home/priorysc/public_html/googlesitemaps/code/GoogleSitemapDecorator.php on line 9

I try removing the googlesitemaps folder, but then it just brings up the error that it can't find the googlesitemaps _config file. Is there any way I can remove the reference to googlesitemaps, or failing that just get the thing to work?

I'm a fairly verse php coder but I don't know that much about silverstripe as it's just been dumped on me.

Anyone know? I'm tearing my hair out over this!

-James

Comment: ehmm... I would say it's just about /?flush=1 - have you?

Answer (score 2):

SiteTreeDecorator was a class that existed in v2.4 of SilverStripe, the fact that the error is saying it doesn't exist tells me you're running v3.0 or higher. Double check which version of SilverStripe you're running, then update the 'googlesitemaps' module to the appropriate version:

- SilverStripe v3.0: https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-googlesitemaps/tree/1.1
- SilverStripe v3.1: https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-googlesitemaps/tree/master